# Domain A record and www

Tags: domain-name

I have a question about domain A records.

I have a VPS and I want to point my domain to its IP.

Now, do I have to add an entry into the A record for mydomain.com AND www.mydomain.com? Or will simply adding an entry for mydomain.com make the www.mydomain.com work automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the two entries you mention is individual and distinct. So if you want both to work, you need to add both.

Comment: It is generally considered a good practice to put the 'www' record as a CNAME, not an A record, assuming it is the same.

Comment: i just put it as an A name and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may add an A record for your IP and a CNAME record for www. or *. like:

```
.domain.tld     A      3600 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (IP)
www.domain.tld  CNAME  3600 domain.tld
```

and/or

```
*.domain.tld    CNAME  3600 domain.tld
```